# Troubleshooting a circuit to control motor speed

Tags: motor-controller

I'm playing around with an old Crosley cruiser. I know what people say about them (the small suitcase record players) but it's a project. Basically have taken everything out (apart from the record player bit itself) and installed a high impedance preamp, better amplifier, better speakers etc.

The one thing I'm struggling with is a pitch control for the motor. It's an EG-530SD-3F motor. It operates off 5 V - 12 V and has two pots on the back of the motor itself to control speed. One for 33 RPM and one for 45 RPM.

Somehow though the Crosley main board adjusted the speed of the DC motor via a 10k potentiometer. I can manually set the two speeds myself via the pots on the motor but it would be nice to have use of the pitch control again so I can tweak the speed.

Can anyone suggest a link to a circuit I could use please? Have currently got 6 V going to the motor as that's what the original motherboard ran on, but could use 12 V if necessary as the new amp inside runs off 12 V. I tried the circuit below:

[image]

But the result using the 10k pot from the Cruiser is that the speed is too slow (even if I adjust the pot on the back of the motor to max speed). It also only appears to adjust the speed a quarter of a turn (doesn't go any faster after that).

Comment: Do you know which motor voltages are needed for 33 and 45 RPM? You can test that with a variable bench top supply.